# Append localstorage data to the body element on All session (Works also with reload)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I have some code from input, and I wanna to save it to some body element. 
I can add it to the body, but it disappear when page is reloaded

```js
function store(){
    var nameOfbook = document.getElementById("nameOfbook");
    var value = localStorage.setItem("nameOfbook", nameOfbook.value);
    var storedValueBockName = localStorage.getItem("nameOfbook");
    var par = document.createElement('P');
    par.innerText = storedValueBockName;
    document.body.appendChild(par);
}
```

```html
<form action="\" class="form-login"  method="post" /> 
    <input name="text" type="text" id="nameOfbook" required="" placeholder="Book name" />
    <button onclick="store()" type="button">StoreText</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: yeh, it works. Thank you a lot, and sorry for delay. @skwidbreth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is basically asking how to retrieve a stored value from `localStorage`.

So you're setting the value in `localStorage`, but when you reload the page, you need to have a script that checks to see if there's a value in `localStorage` and add that data to your page if it is found there.

I would suggest something like:

```
<script>
    var setText = function(text) {
        var par = document.createElement('P');
        par.innerText = text;
        document.body.appendChild(par);
    }

    var checkLocalStorage = function() {
        var value = localStorage.getItem("nameOfbook")

        if (value) {
            setText(value)
        }
    }

    checkLocalStorage()

    function store(){
        var nameOfbook = document.getElementById("nameOfbook");
        var value = localStorage.setItem("nameOfbook", nameOfbook.value);
        var storedValueBockName = localStorage.getItem("nameOfbook");
        setText(storedValueBockName)
    }
</script>
```

So I moved the code that appends the title to the page into its own function so that it can be used by both `store()` and `checkLocalStorage()`. `checkLocalStorage` looks to see if there's a value set for `nameOfbook` and, if there is, passes that value to `setText`.

Should do the trick.